# Calculating the p-values on coefficients in Aalen Additive

Tags: python, survival

I've been digging into the source code of lifelines the excellent package in Python from Cameron Davidson-Pilon. 
However something I'm struggling with is that there's no p-values on regression coefficients or on covariates. I'd like to have an easy way to calculate these, but the literature hasn't been as easy to explore as I thought it would be.

Does anyone know how to calculate these?